# Validation within the Winforms Propertygrid

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, validation

Is it possible to implement input **validation** within the Winforms Propertgrid control? For example how can I validate/define "required fields"? Can I use the **Error Provider**?
Is it possible to use **RequiredAttribute** (System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations)?

Answer (score 6):

Register OnValueChanged event and do the work there!

```
propertyGrid.PropertyValueChanged+=  new PropertyValueChangedEventHandler(propertyGrid_PropertyValueChanged ); 


private void propertyGrid_PropertyValueChanged(object s, PropertyValueChangedEventArgs e) 
    { 
        if (e.ChangedItem.Label == "???" && !IsValid((int)e.ChangedItem.Value) ) 
        { 
            // the entered value is wrong - show error message 
            e.ChangedItem.PropertyDescriptor.SetValue( propertyGrid.SelectedObject, e.OldValue); 
            MessageBox.Show("Wrong Data", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation); 
        } 
    }


    private static bool IsValid( int inputData) 
    { 
      // logic here
    }
```

I hope this will help you to solve the problem!