# WinForms designer properties of different derived types

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-forms-designer, propertygrid

Say I have a particular type that I want to make available to the Windows Forms designer...

```
public class Style
{
    public CustomBrush Brush { get; set; }
}
```

And `CustomBrush` is implemented like so...

```
public abstract CustomBrush
{
    ...
}

public SolidCustomBrush : CustomBrush
{
    ...
}

public GradientCustomBrush : CustomBrush
{
    ...
}
```

Is there a way at design time that I can choose from any of the types derived from `CustomBrush`, instantiate an instance of the selected type, and modify it via the designer?

So far the only way I've though of to be able to do this is using an `enum`

```
enum BrushType
{
    Solid,
    Gradient
}
```

When the `enum` changes, so does type underlying the `Brush` property, but I don't like this approach...it's dirty!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to put an extended WinForms Control on ToolBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116311/how-to-put-an-extended-winforms-control-on-toolbox)

Comment: @Zack That doesn't look like a duplicate.

Comment: @Zack, not even close to what I'm trying to achieve here...

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171840.aspx

Comment: @RezaAghaei I agree. I thought it was a good answer, so I've neutralised the downvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an option you can create a custom [`TypeConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayybcxe5.aspx) that provides a list of standard values to show in `PropertyGrid`.

> A type converter can provide a list of values for a type in a
>   Properties window control. When a type converter provides a set of
>   standard values for a type, the value entry field for a property of
>   the associated type in a Properties window control displays a down
>   arrow that displays a list of values to set the value of the property
>   to when clicked.

Since you want to be able to edit also sub properties of the `CustomBrush` in property grid, you should derive from [`ExpandableObjectConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.expandableobjectconverter(v=vs.110).aspx).

**Result**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Implementation**

Create a `CustomBrushConverter` class and derive from  [`ExpandableObjectConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.expandableobjectconverter(v=vs.110).aspx). Then override these methods:

- [`GetStandardValuesSupported`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.getstandardvaluessupported.aspx): return `true` to show a dropdown.
- [`GetStandardValuesExclusive`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ec10dksk.aspx): return `true` to limit supported values to dropdown list.
- [`GetStandardValues`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.getstandardvalues.aspx): return a list of available options to show in dropdown. All values should be the same type of the property you are editing (here `CustomBrush` type).
- [`CanConvertFrom`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.canconvertfrom.aspx): return `true` if the `sourceType` parameter is of type `string`.
- [`ConvertFrom`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.convertfrom.aspx): return one of standard values based on the string `value` parameter.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq; 
class CustomBrushConverter : ExpandableObjectConverter
{
    CustomBrush[] standardValues = new CustomBrush[] { new SolidCustomBrush(), new GradientCustomBrush() };
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        if (sourceType == typeof(string))
            return true;
        return base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }
    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        var result = standardValues.Where(x => x.ToString() == value).FirstOrDefault();
        if (result != null)
            return result;
        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }
    public override bool GetStandardValuesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return true;
    }
    public override bool GetStandardValuesExclusive(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return true;
    }
    public override StandardValuesCollection GetStandardValues(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return new StandardValuesCollection(standardValues);
    }
}
```

Then decorate the `Brush` property with `TypeConverterAttribute` this way:

```
public class Style /*: Component */
{
    [TypeConverter(typeof(CustomBrushConverter))]
    public CustomBrush Brush { get; set; }
}
```

You can override `ToString` method of your `CustomBrush` classes to provide more friendly names to show in dropdown list in `PropertyGrid`. For example:

```
public class GradientCustomBrush : CustomBrush
{
    public Color Color1 { get; set; }
    public Color Color2 { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Gradient";
    }
}
```

Comment: While the answer is completely correct a downvote is really strange!

Comment: with this answer, say for example someone designs their own brush that extends CustomBrush, can this example be used to dynamically find implementations of CustomBrush, say using reflection, and add them to the list? Would that work?

Comment: The solution is relied on `standardValues` array and instances of `CustomBrush` which it contains. So the answer is Yes. In an implementation I used `ITypeDiscoveryService` to find desired types and added them to the standard values collection.

Comment: Okay, so I've implemented this, however there is a bit of a snag...the dropdown list is definitely along the right lines, but say for example each CustomBrush implementation has properties that I also want to manipulate via the designer (i.e. SolidCustomBrush has a Color property, and I want to set it's Color)...can this be achieved also?

Comment: It's enough to change the base class of your converter to `ExpandableObjectConverter`. Then it allows you to expand the property using `+` sign near the property and edit sub properties. You may find my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33899479/3110834) useful.

Comment: Would this not need to generate two properties in the designer? (1. a dropdown to select the custom implementation, and 2. to design the custom implementation)?

Comment: No it doesn't need. To test it in action, just change the base class to `ExpandableObjectConverter`.

Comment: You know the requirements better, but take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34002791/3110834) too. It's usefull for cases which you want to have some `CustomBrush` components like `Gradiend` and `Solid` and put an instance of one of them on the form and use it as `Brush` of the `Style` component.

Comment: Hello @Reza Aghaei, I found something I can't resolve in approach above. When creating A `list<element>` And each element can choose which Brush to choose. when create new element in CollectionEditor within WinForms designer the new value contains previous element value? How can I resolve this

Comment: Hi @deveton, at the moment I do not have a proper workstation to reproduce the problem; but as soon as have access to a proper workstation, I'll give it a try and will let you know if I have any idea about it; meanwhile, as an option for such editing feature: ...

Comment: ... You can create a custom UiTypeEditor for your brush, which opens a custom dialog; in the dialog you can have a dropdown list (containing your brush types) and a PropertyGrid.  After choosing a brush type from dropdown, create an instance of it and show in PropertyGrid and by pressing an OK button, close the dialog and set the brush instance as value of the property. (Something similar to font dialog.)

Comment: Hello Reza thank you much much. I do it like you said its worked. But some little thing please how to serialize properties as beautiful shape. Like AddRange() for collections. Because designer always generate Brush1 then Brush1.XX = 110 then Brushes.Add(Brush1).  How to do it directly as Brushes.AddRange(new Brush(xx){XX})

Comment: Another question :) Did UiTypeEditor serialize properties to winforms designer. or TypeConverter should provided also

Comment: @deveton About better serialization of the code: it could be a whole new topic itself (a new question), but I guess implementing an instance descriptor, could be of help. Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55060816/3110834), at list it helps you to create the brush like b = new Brush(x,y,z) instead of setting b.X and b.Y and b.Z individually.

Comment: @deveton About UiTypeEditor, it controls the editing part (like showing a modal dialog). Serialization is responsibility of the serialization-related attributes and the type converter.

Comment: Hello @Reza Aghaei. sorry for that. But please the DefaultValue(typeof(class), "") never works with above scenario? How to allow DefaultValue attribute with complex-type specially above case in your answer please. I try ResetValueXX() not working and so on :(

Comment: For example How to make Brush Solid is a default value that appears grayed in PropertyGrid :(