# Create a property with multiple values in CustomControl

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using a Custom TextBox control in WinForms application. I want a property such that it has multiple values just like a combo box. Now when I choose any value in designer mode then how will that value get reflected in the  CustomControl. I am not getting the logic. Kindly give any suggestion or hint.

Please comment if you need more info.

Comment: What should be the behavior of the control? What's your design-time and run-time requirement?

Comment: I need a property to validate, it will have three validationrules - a,b & c (say). Now in design mode when i select b validationrule then validationprovider attached to the customcontrol should use that b validationrule in it.

Comment: If just using showing a dropdown in property grid is enough, you can define an enum containing a, b and c. Then define a public property of type of that enum. This way the property grid will show a dropdown containing enum values for the property.

Comment: If showing just a dropdown for the property is not enough and for example some different properties should be for the selected rule, take a look at this post: [WinForms designer properties of different derived types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37931785/winforms-designer-properties-of-different-derived-types). It's suitable for cases when each validation rule has its own properties.