# How to return a create a Type property of type (Type) in WinForms C# application?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, properties, typeconverter

> This question is self-answered. If you have better answer post it.
> Specially when dealing with NULL value in TypeConverters if you have better
> approach post it

When creating properties like Strings, DateTime, etc.

It appeared well and serialized.

But I need to create a property of `Type` type.

Actually creating a `Type` property but it is un-modifiable.

Is there a converter or such task to allow that?

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    public Type MyType{get;set;}
}
```

[image: Its Grayed]

From picture Its grayed. and read-only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Many special thanks to **@Reza Aghaei** for his awesome answers **Thanks** to
him much.

["Specified cast is not valid" error in TypeConverter.ConvertTo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55084652/specified-cast-is-not-valid-error-in-typeconverter-convertto/55089857?noredirect=1#comment119843033_55089857)

[How to create TypeConverter which accepts multiple values and serialized to WinForms Form.designer.cs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67769086/how-to-create-typeconverter-which-accepts-multiple-values-and-serialized-to-winf)

TypeConverter Implemented as following:

```
public class DataTypeConverter : TypeConverter
{
    private const string NullString = "<NULL>";
    private Type[] types = new Type[] { null, typeof(byte), typeof(short), typeof(int), typeof(long), typeof(decimal), typeof(string), typeof(DateTime), typeof(bool) };
  
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        if (sourceType == typeof(string)) return true;
        return base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }
    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        if (value.ToString() == NullString) return null;
        var result = types.FirstOrDefault(x => x?.ToString() == value.ToString());
        if (result != null)
            return result;
        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }
    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType == typeof(string))
        {
            if (value == null)
                return NullString;
            return value.ToString();
        }
        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }
    public override StandardValuesCollection GetStandardValues(ITypeDescriptorContext context) => new StandardValuesCollection(types);
    public override bool GetStandardValuesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context) => true;
    public override bool GetStandardValuesExclusive(ITypeDescriptorContext context) => true;
}
```

**Result**

[image: result image]